uneven raws in recyclerview using gridlayout manager Android kotlin
The problem is I am trying to design a layout with two columns and no rows or uneven rows this is my current design my current design and this is what I want to achieve expected design.
This is my main activity code:
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recipesView)
        val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager

        recipeAdapter = RecipeAdapterClass(items)
        recyclerView.adapter = recipeAdapter

here is the recyclerview code:
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recipesView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

here is the item layout code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/recipeCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/recipecardwith_ripple_effect"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="3dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="3dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/recipeImage"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/hotdog"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipeTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="160dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Lasagna"
        style="@style/TextColor"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recipeImage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recipeTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recipeDuration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="40 min"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            style="@style/TextColor"/>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" | "
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            style="@style/TextColor"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recipeRating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3.6 "
            android:textSize="18sp"
            style="@style/TextColor"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_star_24"
            app:tint="@color/primary"/>



    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

since I used wrap_content in the imageView the items will never have the same heights, my app stretches the height of the next item in arow to match the height of the larger item which I hate so much.
Any one with an idea please help.
I tried to use custom layout manager but did not go as planned. Any one with a better solution please help

This type problem is called a "Packing Problem".

This looks like a Staggered grid layout manager to me.
